# Listening a particular port on linux to access data comes from mobile device

Tags: linux, centos, listener, port

i am newbie to Linux platform, i am working on java technology.
what i have to do is : Having a program that running on mobile devices,that sends some data to my Linux machine, now i have to create a program in java that

1. listen to a particular port.
2. access data comes on that port(which is sending by mobile device)
3. save that data to the database.
4. response back to the mobile device.

i.e. i would make my Linux system as server that can listen from many clients(mobile devices), but not getting how to configure this environment... :(

i used cent OS 5.4 and
installed jdk1.6.0_24

any help would be appreciated.....

thanx in advance!

khushi

Answer (score 0):

One of Java's greatest strengths is that you can pretty much ignore the host operating system as long as you stick to core Java features. In the case you're describing, you should be able to accomplish everything by simply using the standard Java networking APIs and either the JDBC to access an existing, external database or you could choose any number of embedded Java databases such as [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). For your stated use case, that you'll be running the application on Linux is pretty much irrelevant (which should be good news... you don't need to learn a whole operating system in addition to writing your app ;-).

Comment: hi Rakis, yup i know that i can connect to database using jdbc with mysql. but actualy i want to know that what i should do for port listening.... as you told me that i can use java networking API,but i am not sure that using these APIs would i able to reserve a port on linux server that listen for tcp and udp packets, comes from mobile device...

Comment: The fact that a mobile device is involved is, fortunately, irrelevant. As is the desire to "reserve" a port. Just write some Java code to send and receive TCP & UDP data and let the abstraction model that is TCP/IP sockets do the rest. You're making this entirely too complicated for yourself ;-) Just relax and give it a shot. It'll work; you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a nice client/server tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html), in that it is broken into steps, and adds each new concept in another step.

[Here's another client/server tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html) with much more detail.

I would write it to accept one connection at a time.  Once that works, I would study the new(ish) java.lang.concurrent classes, in particular the ExecutorService, as a way of managing the worker bee handling each connection.  Then change your program to handle multiple connections using those classes.  Breaking it up in two steps like that will be a lot easier.